# Formatting text from a subprocess.Popen command

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I am trying to run a subprocess command and want to format the output to just show the Unix epoch timestamp and the time of creation (preferably convert the human readable time from a 24 hour time to a 12 hour stamp). I have been searching the web for hours and have not found what I am looking for. (The variables(pool, agent, rmpool) in the subprocess command have no bearing to the question)

```
epoch = subprocess.Popen("zfs list -t snapshot -r " + pool + agent +
                         " -o name,creation | " + rmpool + " | grep -v NAME",
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
snap, err = epoch.communicate()
snap = str(snap)
snap = snap.split(' ')
stamp = snap[0]
snaptime = snap[4]
print "\nEpoch\t\tTime"
print stamp, '\t', snaptime
```

It only returns with this

> Epoch      Time
>
> 1370217684 20:01

I need it to return with this:

> Epoch Time
>
> 1370217684    20:01
>
> 1370822507    20:01
>
> 1371427274    20:01
>
> 1371859278    20:01
>
> 1371945679    20:01
>
> 1372032076    20:01
>
> 1372118478    20:01
>
> 1372204879    20:01
>
> 1372291282    20:01

Comment: If you could add an example of the format of raw text that ends up in `snap` variable to your question, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @martineau here is what the snap variable shows:
1370217684 Sun Jun 2 20:01 2013
1370822507 Sun Jun 9 20:01 2013

Comment: Between "2013" and "1370822507" should be a line separation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to iterate through all the values in `snap.split(' ')`:

```
snap, err = epoch.communicate()
print "\nEpoch\t\tTime"
for stamp,_,_,_,snaptime,_ in zip(*[iter(snap.split(' '))]*6):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(stamp, snaptime))
```

The above uses the `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` [grouper idiom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to cluster the data into `n`-length groups.

Comment: for stamp,_,_,_,snaptime = zip(*[iter(snap.split(' '))]*5):
                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Oops, yes. That equal sign should be `in`.

Comment: After changing the "=" to "in" it is working more what I am looking for. The only thing it is print out the year on a separate line